# How can I modify the jsx innerText in a statelesss function?

Tags: reactjs, function, stateless, innertext

How can I edit the paragraph in func from another function?

```
const func = ({ onChange, onDeselect }) => (
  <div>
  <p>Edit this</p>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

add another props:

```
const func = ({ onChange, onDeselect, copy }) => (
  <div>
    <p>{copy}</p>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Thank you !! I am new to React and I still find it confusing. Can you please also tell me how to get a function return to be passed as a prop please?

Comment: For example: function func2() {
  return <h1>This should be passes</h1>;
}, so This should be passed appear in the paragraph?

Comment: Don't know if this is what you mean: http://jsfiddle.net/ypzcne51/1/

`<Foo copy={<Bar />} />`

Answer (score 0):

I want to contentProp to be content but I am exporting this component so the rendering is in another file.

```
let content = <SearchContent />;
function renderTabContent({ getTabContentProps, value }) {
  const SampleTab = SampleTabs[value];
  content = <SampleTab {...getTabContentProps()} />;
}
renderTabContent.propTypes = {
  getTabContentProps: PropTypes.func,
  value: PropTypes.string
};

const TabsApp = ({ onChange, onDeselect, contentProp }) => (
  <div>
    <AppHeader
      data-testod="hearder"
      position="static"
      renderNav={({ getNavProps }) => (
        <div {...getNavProps({})} >
          <Tabs
            centered
            noBorder
            defaultValue={Search}
            displayName={'centeredExample'}
            onChange={onChange}
            onDeselect={onDeselect}
            render={({ getTabProps }) => <Tab {...getTabProps()} />}
            renderTabContent={renderTabContent}
            tabs={[Search, Add, Update]}
          />
        </div>
      )}
    />
    <div>{contentProp}</div>
  </div>
);

TabsApp.propTypes = {
  onChange: PropTypes.func,
  onDeselect: PropTypes.func,
  contentProp: PropTypes.element
};
```